# Регулярное выражение для строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужна строка в JavaScript, которая может содержать одно или более слов, начинающаяся с буквы. Каждое слово может содержать цифры,буквы, тире и подчеркивание между соседними буквами/цифрами. Слова не должны начинаться и заканчиваться тире или подчеркиванием. В конце строки допустимы пробелы. Первое слово обязательно начинается с буквы и может быть длинною 1 или более.

Пока я пришел к следующему

`/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`

Но оно не работает как мне нужно, к сожалению. В частности, выражение типа `a s--5__f` тоже пройдет тест.

Comment: А что не так с вашим контрпримером? Не допускается несколько подряд подчеркиваний или тире?

Comment: @iksuy Да, такое не должно иметь место. Только одно тире или подчеркивание между соседними буквами/цифрами. Например, валидным будет `fdf sdf-sdf-sdf fsd_sd_sdf sd-sd 13`.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+((([A-Za-z0-9])+([\-\_])?)* *)*$` Можно вместо наборов использовать классы alpha и alnum.

Comment: @Akina Уже ближе. Но эти строки `dv d_d-dv 1_`  `sdsv d vs_dd 3- ` тоже пройдут тест

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*\s*$/`, https://regex101.com/r/5noApa/1

Comment: Сегодня я переключился на другие задачи. Завтра проверю и отпишусь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*\s*$/
```

См. [демо выражения онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/5noApa/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[a-zA-Z]` - буква
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 и более букв и цифр
- `(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 и более повторов дефиса или знака подчёркивания, за которыми следует 1 и боле букв/цифр
- `(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*` - 0 и более повторов...

  - `\s` - пробельный символ
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ букв/цифр
  - `(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 и более повторов дефиса или знака подчёркивания, за которыми следует 1 и боле букв/цифр
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.

Пример кода:

```js
var strs = ['fdf sdf-sdf-sdf fsd_sd_sdf sd-sd 13', 'dv d_d-dv 1_', 'sdsv d vs_dd 3-'];
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*\s*$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  if (reg.test(s)) {
    console.log(s, '=>', true)
  } else {
    console.log(s, '=>', false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Работает как надо.